# laravel select where and where condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this basic query i want to perform but an error keeps coming up. Probably due to my newness to laravel.

here is the code:

```
$userRecord = $this->where('email', $email)->where('password', $password);
        echo "first name: " . $userRecord->email;
```

I am trying to get the user record matching the credentials where email AND password are a match. This is throwing an error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$email

I've checked the email and password being passed to the function, and they are holding values. what is the problem here?

Thanks,

Comment: as an aside, you may wish to to look at Eloquent's model scopes for tidying more complex queries.  Suppose your email field was actually emailId with an FK constraint: users_emails_foreign, 

you can do something like:
class Email extends Model {}
class User extends Model { 
 public function scopeEmail($query) {
  return $query->where('emailId',
$Email::whereAddress("test@example.com")->first()->id);
 }
}

Now you could have a call in your code like $user->email()->wherename("Frank");

Answer (score 62):

```
$this->where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)
```

is returning a Builder object which you could use to append more where filters etc.

To get the result you need:

```
$userRecord = $this->where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)->first();
```

Comment: I am getting Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: if you're getting it when you call $userRecord->email;
Then $userRecord is null as the query didn't return any records.

Comment: Yes could be the case but why so? I echoed email and password and both showed exactly to what is in database. Any thing I might be overlooking?

Comment: Is the password being stored as a hashed value, which you should do? Then checking using the where clause won't work. It's better to user the built in Auth functions for validating users logins.

Comment: this is perhaps redundant query isnt it

Answer (score 15):

You either need to use `first()` or `get()` to fetch the results :

```
$userRecord = $this->where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)->first();
```

You most likely need to use `first()` as you want only one result returned.

If the record isn't found `null` will be returned. If you are building this query from inside an Eloquent class you could use `self` .

for example :

```
$userRecord = self::where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)->first();
```

More info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects)

Comment: I tried this and I get "Trying to get property of non-object" @afarazit

Comment: and still it doesn't work mate. I am getting the same error :(

Comment: You must update your question then and  provide more info on where you're trying to run this code, provide the full class if possibly

Comment: I am trying to run this code within User model. Hence I am using $this and self. Nevertheless, in my controller I am invoking the function $user->login($email, $password) and this is supposed to return the found user record.

Comment: @spacemonkey where is `$user` coming from in your controller? Apparently `$user` isn't instantiating correctly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42743/discussion-between-afarazit-and-spacemonkey)

Comment: I figured out something. When I changed the string $userRecord = $this->where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)->first(); to $userRecord = $this->where('email', $email)->first(); it actually passed the if condition and loaded the correct page. I need both email and password to be checked. any hints there?

Comment: @spacemonkey, may be it is not matching because in most cases password will be encoded in to some encrypt format and here you are matching it directly.

Answer (score 11):

```
$userRecord = Model::where([['email','=',$email],['password','=', $password]])->first();
```

or

```
$userRecord = self::where([['email','=',$email],['password','=', $password]])->first();
```

I`
think this condition is better then 2 where. Its 
where condition array in array of where conditions;

Answer (score 6):

The error is coming from `$userRecord->email`. You need to use the `->get()` or `->first()` methods when calling from the database otherwise you're only getting the `Eloquent\Builder` object rather than an `Eloquent\Collection`

The `->first()` method is pretty self-explanatory, it will return the first row found. `->get()` returns all the rows found

```
$userRecord = Model::where('email', '=', $email)->where('password', '=', $password)->get();
echo "First name: " . $userRecord->email;
```

Answer (score 6):

After reading your previous comments, it's clear that you misunderstood the Hash::make function. Hash::make uses bcrypt hashing. By design, this means that every time you run Hash::make('password'), the result will be different (due to random [salting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177796/am-i-misunderstanding-what-a-hash-salt-is)). That's why you can't verify the password by simply checking the hashed password against the hashed input.

The proper way to validate a hash is by using:

```
Hash::check($passwordToCheck, $hashedPassword);
```

So, for example, your login function would be implemented like this:

```
public static function login($email, $password) {
    $user = User::whereEmail($email)->first();
    if ( !$user ) return null;  //check if user exists
    if ( Hash::check($password, $user->password) ) {
        return $user;
    } else return null;
}
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```
$user = User::login('email@aol.com', 'password');
if ( !$user ) echo "Invalid credentials.";
else echo "First name: $user->firstName";
```

I recommend reviewing the [Laravel security documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords), as functions already exist in Laravel to perform this type of authorization.

Furthermore, if your custom-made hashing algorithm generates the same hash every time for a given input, it's a security risk. A good one-way hashing algorithm should use random salting.

Answer (score 4):

Here is shortest way of doing it.

```
$userRecord = Model::where(['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password])->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$userRecord = $this->where('email', $email)->where('password', $password);
```

in the above code , you are just requesting for Eloquent object , not requesting for the data,

```
   $userRecord = $this->where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)->first();
```

so that, you can get the first data, from the given credentials by default ordering **DESC with PK**, in case of multiple data with the same credentials. but you have to handle the exception, in case of no matching data.
you have one more option to achieve the same.

```
$userRecord = $this->where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)->firstOrfail();
```

in the above snippets, in case of no data, it will automatically throw a **404** error.

also, you can have alternative snippets

```
$filter['email']=$email;
$filter['password']=$password;
$userRecord = $this->where($filter)->first();
```

That's it