# MySQL hashed column password+script bash

Tags: mysql, bash, sha1, openvpn

I'd a little problem.

I'd created a MySQL table with the password column encrypted with SHA1.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_encrypted (
    username varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 'username',
    hashed_password varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'password',
    user_mail varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL DEFAULT 'your@email.com',
    user_phone varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL DEFAULT '+33 1 23 45 67 89',
    user_online tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    user_enable tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    user_max_connection tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
    user_start_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2015-05-01',
    user_end_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    KEY  hashed_password (hashed_password)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Result

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

I'd a script, which call the MySQL table :

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/openvpn/script/config.sh

#New Encrypted_password
#username=$(mysql -h$HOST -P$PORT -u$USER -p$PASS $DB -sN -e "select username from user_encrypted where username = '$username' AND hashed_password = '$password' AND user_enable=1 AND user_max_connection=2 AND user_start_date != user_end_date AND TO_DAYS(now()) >= TO_DAYS(user_start_date) AND (TO_DAYS(now()) <= TO_DAYS(user_end_date) OR user_end_date='0000-00-00')")

##Check user
[ "$username" != '' ] && [ "$username" = "$username" ] && echo "user : $username" && echo 'authentication ok.' && exit 0 || echo 'authentication failed.'; exit 1
```

The problem is, when I use the script, and OpenVPn ask me for user / password, I use Test  and Test1234, but, the system refuse the password.
It seems the 'non-encrypted" password can't be translated to encrypted password for checking if the password for the table is the same as i entered in the client OpenVPN.

I don't know how to do, in my script bash for the password I enter is "converted" to encrypted password for checking with the database...

Rhank you

Comment: Just a note: it's hashed, not encrypted. Latter can be decrypted, former cannot.

Comment: Another note: You should [salt the password](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2178251/4811803) before hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Your bash script doesn't hash the password. Hence, you're comparing the password with a *hash* of the password.

You say it's a SHA1 hash, which conveniently exists as [a built-in function in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1). Changing

```
where username = '$username' AND hashed_password = '$password' ...
```

into

```
where username = '$username' AND hashed_password = SHA1('$password') ...
```

should fix your immediate problem.

I want to bring up two other problems with your code -- these are unfortunately pretty common mistakes:

1. It appears you are not using a salt for the password hash. You should -- it would make it significantly harder for attackers to figure out your password from the hash. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2178251/4811803).
2. Your login script is vulnerable to SQL injection. What if an attacker puts a string like `admin'; SELECT * FROM user_encrypted WHERE 0 AND '` (or something to that effect) as a username? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332367/4811803).

Comment: Hi Snild Dolkow,

Thanks for your answer.
I was so fast for posting my problem, because after thinking about some minutes, I solved it by myself.

This case can be closed, or can be used for sysadmin Jr when they don't know how to do ;)

Thnaks again.